# Using AngularJS ng-bind and ng-href together?

Tags: angularjs

Using AngularJS, I've noticed a pattern that seems wrong to me.

When building a table, my data is bound using ng-bind. But if I need the text in the cell to link to something, the link has to get created manually.

A non-linked table cell looks like:

```
<td ng-bind="customer.name"></td>
```

But if I want to create a link, I do:

```
<td><a ng-href="/customer/{{customer.id}}">{{customer.name}}</a></td>
```

Is there a way to create the link using attributes? Something like:

```
<td ng-bind="customer.name" ng-href="/customer/{customer.id}"></td>
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use `ng-bind`, yes, but inside the `<a>`, like @btford said.

```
<td><a ng-href="/customer/{{customer.id}}" ng-bind="customer.name"></a></td>
```

Answer (score 7):

This isn't really an AngularJS issue; this is more about how HTML works. HTML doesn't allow you to just add an `href` attribute to any element to create a link. You need to use the anchor tag to create a link.

If you want, you could [write a directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) that produces the anchor tag inside cells. But that hardly seems worth it, and most would probably agree that it produces less semantic, more confusing markup.

HTML links spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html